# JSON scope change not reflecting in view in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Actually i have json scope in controller

```
  bosAppModule.controller("module-menu-controller", function($scope, $compile, $http, layoutRenderingDataFactory) { 
        $scope.transactionalData={};
        $scope.transactionalData.Data={"entityinfo":{"entity":"","tenantId":"292FEC76-5F1C-486F-85A5-09D88096F098","timeStamp":"2015-12-15T10:16:06.322Z"},"collections":{}};
    });
```

$scope.transactionalData will be filled based on the user input. I mean it's two way binding. The complete JSON like finally.

```
 {
      "entityinfo": {
        "entity": "Customer29Jan16",
        "tenantid": "292FEC76-5F1C-486F-85A5-09D88096F098",
        "timestamp": "2015-12-15T10:16:06.322Z"
      },
      "collections": {
        "customer29jan16": {
          "rowset": [
            {
              "cuid": "6293f82f-d202-45c0-9a7b-46cd955361a3",
              "name": "test",
              "quantity": "60",
              "rate": "60",
              "amount": "3600"
            }
          ],
          "meta": {
            "parentreference": "***",
            "pkname": "***",
            "fkname": "***"
          },
          "rowfilter": []
        },
        "customer29jan16obj": {
          "rowset": [
            {
              "cuobjid": "83bfc652-9f83-47d3-b173-b1a824ff3bed",
              "fulladdress": "Electronic City",
              "objaddr": "Bangalore",
              "objname": "Testing",
              "customer29jan16objcuid": "6293f82f-d202-45c0-9a7b-46cd955361a3"
            }
          ],
          "meta": {
            "parentreference": "***",
            "pkname": "***",
            "fkname": "***"
          },
          "rowfilter": []
        }
      }
    }
```

Once the this JSON values persited in the DB. We have to clear the scope.  we are accessing this scope outside like this.
It's not clear. but scope getting change.

```
// get the scope of module and menu controller
            var moduleMenuControllerScope = angular.element("[ng-controller=module-menu-controller]").scope();

            // clear the crudObject
            moduleMenuControllerScope.transactionalData.Data.collections = {}; 
            moduleMenuControllerScope.$digest();
```

One thing i want to added here. If i will change particular form field then it's changing the view.

Anyone please advice me how to clear the scope and need to relect in view.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Isn't there a AJAX call which saves data in DB?

Comment: What do you mean by "clear the scope"?

Comment: @RahulB - Yes we are using Ajax call

Comment: @ChrisStanley I meant to say when ever we are changing the scope the view should need to reflect.

Comment: Can you show how do you renders this json?

Comment: @MaKCbIMKo It's complicated to create fiddle or something. because so many things need to be place. Everything we are creating dynamically

Comment: Why dont you empty the transactionalData.Data.collections after the success of the call?

Comment: You should be able to wrap it in a $timeout for it to update.  I never recommend using $apply or $digest.

Comment: the issue is probably in bindings. and it will help to see how you do this.

Answer (score -1):

instead of using `$digest` you try `$apply`. It will solve your problem.

Comment: I tried it's showing error $apply already in progress but view not getting change.

Comment: Not working. Is possible please provide any examples related to my requirement. Thanks

Comment: use apply like: `(!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply()` it would be disappear already in progress error.